# Matching data from XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need help with PHP. I'm a complete noob at this. This is what I put together after googling. I'm trying to test if a variable ($steam_id) exist in the xml (steamID64). If so, echo this, if not, echo that.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$steam_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'steam_steamid', true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791459745725/memberslistxml/?xml=1');

foreach ($xml->members as $members) {
    if ($members->steamID64 == $steam_id) {
        echo 'Thank You for Joining our Steam Group';
    } else {
        echo 'Please Join our Steam Group';
    }
}
```

Instead of for each member, it stops at the first member, 76561198198810261.
What am I doing wrong? or perhaps a better way? Thank you!

Comment: Hopefully there are people here who know what this XML looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The `steamID64` is the array, not the members. So if my guess is right, it should be something like this:

```
$ids = $xml->members->steamID64;

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    if ($id == $steam_id) {
        echo 'Thank You for Joining our Steam Group';
    } else {
        echo 'Please Join our Steam Group';
    }
}
```